# TFS2013 : Backlog Overview Report Stuck At Loading

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

I am facing a problem with the TFS2013 Backlog Overview Report. It takes forever to load, stuck at the loading screen. I had waited it for hours, until it show a message says something about request timeout. This behavior only happen in Backlog Overview report but not the other reports. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 3.0 process template for my team project.

I had already tried to manually process the data warehouse and the analysis services following this link: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237(v=vs.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400237%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) but still no help.

I had even reconfigured my Reporting Services, delete my existing data warehouse and analysis service and then rebuild them by using TFS Administration Console but that report still behave the same.

Then, I upgraded my TFS 2013 to Update 2. And then, update my SQL Server 2012 SP1 with Cumulative Update 2. Then, again rebuild my data warehouse and analysis service. But, still fail.

I even tried to create a new team project, then try to open the same Backlog Overview report for this new project, it also behave the same! The report still takes forever to load despite no data in the new team project.

I had run out of idea in troubleshooting this. Appreciate that if you can help me.

EDIT:

I discover that when I load the Backlog Overview Report, my SQL Server (sqlservr.exe) process memory usage grow gradually until it utilizing all my server available memory. I can see the usage grow from 2GB to 28GB in 2 mins time. This SQL Server is dedicated for TFS use only. I closed the report, then wait for the next day to check the SQL Server memory usage again, the memory usage never reduce, is this SQL Server memory leak symptom?

Comment: The SQL doesn't release the unused memory (only if you restart the SQL instance); this is by design.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the SQL profiler before you click on Backlog Overview report and check what SQL statement is using.
Also check the warehouse and cube processing status by using the GetProcessingStatus method of the WarehouseControlService.asmx or by using the Cube Status report from [Administrative Report Pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/07/12/administrative-report-pack-for-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx) (it is for TFS2010 but it can be used also for TFS2013)